# Jow to extract the fields using json serde in hive

Tags: hive

That is the data which is in JSON format and I'm supposed to extract some fields from it,"You have subscribed to Gnip data feed for Twitter and have received the feeds in the json format. Use HIVE Json serde to extract the following fields using HIVE.

[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ov7B.png)

Need a plan to sort out this problem

Comment: Please don't post data as images.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the sample data structure.

To get json data into hive, we need to use get_json_object function.